# Much faster computational time in Python

Tags: python, performance, time

I have this code which reorders a list of names of companies according to the jaccard distance. It's working OK.

However, if I use this code for the names of 30 thousands companies, the computational time is too long. For example I ran this code 2 hours ago and it's still processing.

How can I run much faster this code?. Maybe some libraries or changing the structure?

```
      def jack(a,b):
            x=a.split()
            y=b.split()
            k=float(len(set(x)&set(y)))/float(len((set(x) | set(y))))
            return k

t=['bancorp', 'bancorp', 'bancorp ali', 'bancorp puno', 'bancorp amo', 'gas eu', 'gas', 'profeta', 'bancorp america', 'uni', 'gas for', 'gas tr']

out = [] # this will be the sorted list
for index, val1 in enumerate(t): # work through each item in the original list
    if val1 not in out: # if we haven't already put this item in the new list
        out.append(val1) # put this item in the new list
    for val2 in t[index+1:]: # search the rest of the list
        if val2 not in out: # if we haven't already put this item in the new list
            if jack(val1, val2) >= 0.5: # and the new item is close to the current item
                out.append(val2) # add the new item too
```

Then, the the output is:

```
print out

['bancorp', 'bancorp ali', 'bancorp puno', 'bancorp amo', 'bancorp america', 'gas eu', 'gas', 'gas for', 'gas tr', 'profeta', 'uni']
```

Comment: Your algorithm is O(n^3) due to the `val2 not in out` check. By keeping a set of all the available items you could get it down to O(n^2) which is still slow, but not totally unviable. If you want to stick with the quadratic approach, you're probably better off rewriting this in a compiled language like C++ because the constant factor is pretty high

Comment: Is that your actual code? Because `jack(val1, val2) > 0.3:` is a Syntax Error. Even if you fix that by putting an `if` before it, the output is `['bancorp', 'bancorp ali', 'bancorp puno' ...]`, which is different from what you claimed. Please post the code that produced the output you got.

Comment: could you elaborate in your question why you chose this 0.3 threshhold? this seems arbitrary, and it could be that the list is not correctly sorted: If you catch a guy in a list that is barely bigger than 0.3, then this guy will be appended, even if there is a 1.0 guy further down the list. I think you need to give more context, otherwise it will be hard to optimize.

Comment: Note that `t[index+1:]` will create a *copy* of the list. It *might* be faster to use `itertools.islice`, as in: `islice(t, index+1, len(t))` For small sizes this is probably slower, but with big lists the overhead of allocating that copy should become quite bigger then the overhead of the generator.

Comment: @Bakuriu It's just a constant factor though. Since OP already has an extra 30000 factor to worry about, the estimated 1.2 factor that you're pointing out is not really a problem

Comment: Check my edit, It´s better explained.

Comment: @NiklasB. I don't know where you compute the "1.2 factor". What I know is that avoiding a list copy means *halving* the number of iterations. Sure, one is at C-level so I wouldn't expect to reduce the timing by half. Also it's possible that avoiding creating all those lists prevents some useless garbage collections.

Comment: In my honest opinion, this algorithm doesn't make sense. Why the threshhold? If this were to make any kind of sense, you need the maximum jaccard value, not just a threshhold. There is all kinds of wierd stuff that can happen

Comment: @Bakuriu As I said, it's just a rough estimate. But even a very optimistic 10 times improvement wouldn't buy us a lot here

Comment: How long does it take when run on the latest PyPy?

Comment: @ErikAllik I can't imagine this finishing any time soon independent of the programming language or runtime environment used, since it does hundreds of trillions(!) of costly operations (computing Jaccard distance)

Comment: The treeshold is arbitrary, I choose that value because I consider in that way the names will be very similar, so there's a high probability that they are actually the same name.

Comment: @NiklasB. good point, didn't delve into the code; but if he can get it down to the average world life expectancy, he might be able to squeeze another 2-3x times out of with using PyPy.

Comment: @CreamStat: This will make you miss very high matches if the list is ordered in a unlucky way! computation of the maximum and a certain threshhold is important

Comment: I explain to you the process, this list is the clean version of another list. In the other list I lowercase the names, remove punctuation and the most common names in the list. So a new list is created and that's the input of this code.

Comment: This is maybe a strange issue..  You seem to be trying to find a total ordering on a high dimensional metric space.  That's asking a very high dimension equivalent of `sorted([1, 0+1j])`, which is absurd... What are you really trying to do here?  Do you want neighbors to be clustered together?

Comment: Yes, clusters of similar names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the suggestions of others above, I rolled my own better-performing code.  As identified by Niklas B., the main improvement is reduction from O(n^3) to O(n^2).

```
from __future__ import division
import itertools

def jack(a,b):
    #print "jack", a, b, len(a & b) / len(a | b)
    return len(a & b) / len(a | b)

def jacksort(t):
    # precompute the word set of each input
    sts = [(i, it, set(it.split())) for i, it in enumerate(t)]
    # allow O(1) testing for 'word already in output'
    os = set()
    out = [] # this will be the sorted list
    # work through each item in the original list
    for index, val1, sval1 in sts:
        if not val1 in os:
            out.append(val1) # put this item in the new list
            os.add(val1)
        for index2, val2, sval2 in itertools.islice(sts, index+1, len(sts)):
            # search the rest of the list
            if val2 in os: continue
            if jack(sval1, sval2) >= 0.5:
                # the new item is close to the current item
                out.append(val2) # add the new item too
                os.add(val2)

    return out

def main(n=100):
    t=['bancorp', 'bancorp', 'bancorp ali', 'bancorp puno', 'bancorp amo',
        'gas eu', 'gas', 'profeta', 'bancorp america', 'uni', 'gas for',
        'gas tr']
    t += [" ".join(w.split()) for w in open("/usr/share/dict/words").read().split()]
    t = t[:n]
    jacksort(t)
```

where n is the input size to test.  My /usr/share/dict/words is /usr/share/dict/american-english from debian package wamerican version 7.1-1.

Some timings of my code:

```
   10: 10 loops, best of 3: 30.6 msec per loop
   20: 10 loops, best of 3: 28.9 msec per loop
   50: 10 loops, best of 3: 29.6 msec per loop
  100: 10 loops, best of 3: 31.7 msec per loop
  200: 10 loops, best of 3: 38.7 msec per loop
  500: 10 loops, best of 3: 85.1 msec per loop
 1000: 10 loops, best of 3: 261 msec per loop
 2000: 10 loops, best of 3: 1.01 sec per loop
 5000: 10 loops, best of 3: 6.16 sec per loop
10000: 10 loops, best of 3: 25.3 sec per loop
```

compared to the original code adapted to my test harness:

```
   10: 10 loops, best of 3: 34.1 msec per loop
   20: 10 loops, best of 3: 34.3 msec per loop
   50: 10 loops, best of 3: 33.9 msec per loop
  100: 10 loops, best of 3: 43.1 msec per loop
  200: 10 loops, best of 3: 74.9 msec per loop
  500: 10 loops, best of 3: 415 msec per loop
 1000: 10 loops, best of 3: 2.35 sec per loop
 2000: 10 loops, best of 3: 14.8 sec per loop
 5000: [did not finish while preparing this post]
```

Using timeit at the commandline to generate the numbers:

```
$ for i in 10 20 50 100 200 500 1000 2000 5000 10000; do printf "%5d: " $i; python -mtimeit 'import ojack as jack' 'jack.main('$i')'; done
```

Testing was performed on Python version 2.7.5-5 on Debian amd64, i5-3320m CPU.  Both functions seem to grow in execution time about like big-O notation claims they will.

My input is different than your input, because my "words" are almost all single letters, though each term will turn out to have 5-7 "words" in it.  I don't know whether in practice this means your input would perform worse or better, since you didn't show much about your input.  In fact, I did one run with n=30000, and got 393 seconds.  This is a fair bit more than O(n^2) would have predicted (25.3*9 = 227.7), so there must be a log n lurking in there somewhere despite the O(1) claims of Python sets.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import partial
print sorted(list(set(t)), key=partial(jack,min(t)),reverse=True)
```

might do the same thing (its not quite the same answer... not sure if it is still a correct answer or not)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the algorithmic improvements others have mentioned, you should be able to optimize `jack` significantly by precomputing the set representation of each item.

```
# untested code, but you get the idea
jackDict = dict(map(lambda x: (x, set(x.split())), t))

def jack(a,b):
  x = jackDict[a]
  y = jackDict[b]
  xy = x&y              # single set operation per call to jack()
  return float(len(xy))/float(len(x)+len(y)-len(xy)))
```

Alternatively, it might be faster to compute `|` than `&` on the sets, so you might try instead

```
def jack(a,b):
  x = jackDict[a]
  y = jackDict[b]
  xy = x|y              # single set operation per call to jack()
  return float(len(x)+len(y)-len(xy))/float(len(xy)))
```

Both should be entirely equivalent to your original `jack` function, but you will have to measure performance on your own machine to decide.

Comment: In Python2, you can get rid of the `float()` by using `from __future__ import division`. In Python3, this isn't even needed.

Answer (score 0):

My take at it.

```
t = ['bancorp', 'bancorp', 'bancorp ali', 'bancorp puno', 'bancorp amo', 'gas eu', 'gas', 'profeta', 'bancorp america', 'uni', 'gas for', 'gas tr']

def jack(a, b):
    x, y = a.split(), b.split()
    return float(len(set(x) & set(y))) / len((set(x) | set(y)))

seen = set()
source = list(t)
res = []
while source:
    val = source.pop(0)
    if val not in seen:
        seen.add(val)
        res.append(val)
    tmp = []
    for val2 in source:
        if jack(val, val2) >= 0.5 and val2 not in seen:
            seen.add(val2)
            tmp.append(val2)
    tmp.sort(key=lambda i: jack(val, i), reverse=True)
    res.extend(tmp)

print(res)
```

I've made a few modifications over the initial code:

- sets are used because they're O(1) on average for `x in s`;
- after adding a new value, all other values are filtered and then sorted again for maximum similarity.

---

**NEW IDEA (Please read if interested and adapt it to work against the OP's specification!)**

However, this is still too slow, because it's making too many inner loops at every iteration. **Sketch** of a new idea:

1. Precompute the nearest word for every word. This is accomplished by looping through all the words, picking the one that gives the highest `jack()` value, and storing it into a dictionary, effectively creating a graph.
2. Starting from the first word, look to the next one in the graph and add it to the result. Continue to do this for all the words.

Something *along the lines of*:

```
source = list(t)
pre_computed = {}
while source:
    val = source.pop(0)
    pre_computed[val] = max(source or [''], key=lambda i: jack(val, i))
source2 = list(t)
last = source2.pop(0)
res = [last]
while True:
    val = pre_computed[last]
    if val: res.append(val)
    else: break
    last = val
```

This could work, but currently it gives, for the input above:

```
['bancorp', 'bancorp ali', 'bancorp puno', 'bancorp amo', 'bancorp america', 'uni', 'gas for', 'gas tr']
```

Comment: Using just 12 names the ouput it's what I expected. I've run your code for the 30 thousand names. Let's hope it works in reasonable time !

Comment: @CreamStat: I am already doing that, and it's running from 1 minute already. My hardware is shit though. Let it run for 5-10 minutes and stop it if it does not finish in time. Probably we can make it way better.

Comment: @CreamStat: Also, I have to point out that I've added that line with `sort()` which wasn't in the original code, to have maximum similarity. But if that is not required we can safely remove it and the speedup would be great.

Comment: I stopped it because it didn´t finish as you said.

Comment: @CreamStat: As I expected. I'm working on a new method.

Comment: @CreamStat: I've written a sketch of my idea, hoping that someone will be able to adapt it, since I won't be able to think about this until the next morning.